# valgrind memory leak errors when using pthread_create

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, pthreads, valgrind

I'm writing a program using the pthread library. When I run my program with the command `valgrind --leak-check=full`, I get the following errors description:

```
==11784==  
==11784== **HEAP SUMMARY:**  
==11784==     in use at exit: 4,952 bytes in 18 blocks  
==11784==   total heap usage: 1,059 allocs, 1,041 frees, 51,864 bytes allocated  
==11784==  
==11784== **288 bytes** in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 2 of 3  
==11784==    at 0x4C2380C: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:467)  
==11784==    by 0x4010D2E: _dl_allocate_tls (dl-tls.c:300)  
==11784==    by 0x55DC218: **pthread_create**@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (allocatestack.c:570)  
==11784==    by 0x401BC0: initdevice(char*) (in /a/fr-01/vol/home/stud/lim/workspace  /Ex3/l)  
==11784==    by 0x406D05: main (in /a/fr-01/vol/home/stud/lim/workspace/Ex3/l)  
==11784==  
==11784== **4,608 bytes** in 16 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 3 of 3  
==11784==    at 0x4C2380C: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:467)  
==11784==    by 0x4010D2E: _dl_allocate_tls (dl-tls.c:300)  
==11784==    by 0x55DC218: **pthread_create**@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (allocatestack.c:570)    
==11784==    by 0x40268F: write2device(char*, int) (in /a/fr-01/vol/home/stud/lim/workspace/Ex3/l)  
==11784==    by 0x406D7B: main (in /a/fr-01/vol/home/stud/lim/workspace/Ex3/l)  
==11784==  
==11784== **LEAK SUMMARY:**  
==11784==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks  
==11784==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks  
==11784==      possibly lost: 4,896 bytes in 17 blocks  
==11784==    still reachable: 56 bytes in 1 blocks  
==11784==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks  
==11784== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.  
==11784== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes  
==11784==  
==11784== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v  
==11784== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 4 from 4)
```

---

Every time I call `pthread_create`, with a certain function - I call the function `pthread_exit` in the end of the function. So, after verifying this is not the problem, what could be the problem?

Comment: So did you try to write a program that just do pthread_create/pthread_exit (+join) and run it under valgrind?

Comment: try running it with "--leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes". A guess is that structures that are duplicated might not get deleted. But without code to test it myself I can't say much.

Comment: are you joining your threads with `pthread_join`? otherwise a leak is to be expected.

Answer (score 43):

A thread's resources are not immediately released at termination, unless
the thread was created with the `detach state` attribute set to
`PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED`, or if `pthread_detach` is called for
its `pthread_t`.

An undetached thread will remain terminated state until its identifier is passed to `pthread_join` or `pthread_detach`.

To sum it up, you have three options:

1. create your thread with detached attribute set(PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED attribute)
2. Detach your thread after creation (by calling `pthread_detach`), or
3. Join with the terminated threads to recycle them (by calling `pthread_join`).

Hth.

Comment: Please look at my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41057644/memory-leakage-in-windows-pthread-pthread-join-does-not-deallocate-memory . This answer is useful but did not help me.

Answer (score 6):

You can make the thread [in detached state](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/) to avoid the memory leak if the thread should not be joined (or just expires on it's own).

> To explicitly create a thread as joinable or detached, the attr argument in the pthread_create() routine is used. The typical 4 step process is:

- Declare a pthread attribute variable of the `pthread_attr_t` data type
- Initialize the attribute variable with `pthread_attr_init()`
- Set the attribute detached status with `pthread_attr_setdetachstate()`
- When done, free library resources used by the attribute with `pthread_attr_destroy()`

Comment: I've checked this out a little bit, and found out that when i call 'pthread_detach' **instead of** pthread_exit - there's no memory leak problem like that i've mentioned above. Is it okay to do that and not write 'pthread_exit' at all?

Comment: The man page says: `The pthread_join() or pthread_detach() functions should eventually be called for every thread that is created so that storage associated with the thread may be reclaimed`

Comment: I've already read this man page. It still doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Ah, sorry: `An implicit call to pthread_exit() is made when a thread other than the thread in which main() was first invoked returns from the start
       routine that was used to create it. The function's return value shall serve as the thread's exit status` You can leave it out

Answer (score 5):

when not working with joinable threads the exiting thread needs to call `pthread_detach(pthread_self())`
in order to release all its resources.

Comment: pthread_detach(pthread_self()) works for me (stop valgrind from reporting memory leaks).  This approach is also convenient since keep tracking of all threads started and do pthread_join() is rather hard when threads are dynamically created.

Comment: Some confusion here. Threads can be either joinable, or detached. It is an error to `pthread_detach` a detached thread, so it can only be called for a joinable thread. When "not working with a joinable thread", a simple return from the top-level function releases all resources.

Answer (score 2):

Please note that the default pthread_create behavior is "joinable" NOT DETACHED.
Therefore some OS resources would still remain in the process after pthread finished, which would result in zombie pthread and leads to increased VIRTUAL/resident memory usage.

The four solution @sehe mentioned would fix this problem.

However if you thread is a long-standing one, this might not be really needed.
for example, if the pthread lives through the whole life of the process.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the correct answers given you by other users, I suggest you to read this:

[Tracking down a memory leak in multithreaded C application](http://bl0rg.krunch.be/memleak-pthreads.html)