# pthread_create memory leak?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, pthreads

Whenever I run valgrind on my program, it is telling that I have possibly lost memory wherever I call pthread_create. I have been trying to follow the guidance on

[valgrind memory leak errors when using pthread_create](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5610677/valgrind-memory-leak-errors-when-using-pthread-create)
http://gelorakan.wordpress.com/2007/11/26/pthead_create-valgrind-memory-leak-solved/

and other various websites google gave me, but nothing has worked. So far I have tried joining the threads, setting an pthread_attr_t to DETACHED, calling pthread_detach on each thread, and calling pthread_exit().

trying PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED -

```
pthread_attr_t attr;
pthread_attr_init(&attr);
pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);

pthread_create(&c_udp_comm, &attr, udp_comm_thread, (void*)this);
pthread_create(&drive, &attr, driving_thread, (void*)this);
pthread_create(&update, &attr, update_server_thread(void*)this);
```

I think I may have coded this next one with joining wrong...I am going by 
https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/
and they have all their threads in an array so they just for loop. But I don't have them all in an array so I tried to just change it to work. Please tell me if I did it wrong.

```
void* status;
pthread_attr_t attr;
pthread_attr_init(&attr);
pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);

pthread_create(&c_udp_comm, &attr, udp_comm_thread, (void*)this);
pthread_create(&drive, &attr, driving_thread, (void*)this);
pthread_create(&update, &attr, update_server_thread(void*)this);

pthread_join(c_udp_comm, &status);
pthread_join(drive, &status);
pthread_join(update, &status);
```

trying pthread_detach -

```
pthread_create(&c_udp_comm, NULL, udp_comm_thread, (void*)this);
pthread_create(&drive, NULL, driving_thread, (void*)this);
pthread_create(&update, NULL, update_server_thread(void*)this);

pthread_detach(c_udp_comm);
pthread_detach(drive);
pthread_detach(update);
```

trying pthread_exit -

```
pthread_create(&c_udp_comm, NULL, udp_comm_thread, (void*)this);
pthread_create(&drive, NULL, driving_thread, (void*)this);
pthread_create(&update, NULL, update_server_thread(void*)this);

pthread_exit(NULL);
```

If anyone can help me figure out why none of this is working I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

glibc doesn't free thread stacks when threads exit; it caches them for reuse, and only prunes the cache when it gets huge. Thus it always "leaks" some memory.

Answer (score 2):

You can prove there's no leak by taking your code that uses `pthread_join` and repeating the create/join process a few times. You'll see that the amount of memory "leaked" does not change, proving that no memory was actually leaked at all.